# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at file

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am using phonegap and every time it gives me error at this line .I am trying to submit the form through phonegap , javascript works but with jquery it always me this errro Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at file

```
  jQuery(function() {
```

Here Is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
  <head> 

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"> 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>



  <script>
  function validation()
  {
    alert('validation');
  }

  jQuery(function() {

    alert("login");
    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /*clear result div*/

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    //var values = $(this).serialize();
    var values = "user";
    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: server_url,
      type: "post",
      data: values,
      success: function() {
        alert("success");
        jQuery("#result").html('submitted successfully');
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("failure");
        jQuery("#result").html('there is error while submit');
      }   
    });
  });

  </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have jQuery file in the folder your current page is, also try to get the latest jQuery file you are using quite old, you can download latest [here](http://jquery.com/download/).

Answer (score 0):

Is Cordova based on jQuery ? If so, you have to include jQuery first.

If not, your jQuery file is probably not found. Press Ctrl+u to see the source code, and then click on the link jquery-1.6.4.min.js in the head, and see if it opens your file ?